# Sharing image - Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I can share files those added from other folders except camera. I am getting following exception in Lenova K3 Note.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/9016-4EF8/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180317_111252.jpg
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
   <files-path
       name="Camera"
       path="/Camera/" />
   <files-path
       name="Files"
       path="." />
   <external-path
       name="Downloads"
       path="/Download/" />
   <external-path
       name="WhatsApp"
       path="/WhatsApp/" />
   <external-path
       name="Camera"
       path="/Camera/" />
   <external-path
       name="Others"
       path="." />
   <external-files-path
       name="Camera"
       path="/Camera/" />
   <external-files-path
       name="Files"
       path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Is it possible with any other device?

Comment: @ShaluTD Yes, It is possible with other devices like Mi A1, Moto G5, Nokia 6

Comment: Pro-tips: you don't need to sign your questions, nor state how much you will appreciate answer (highly or otherwise). We try to encourage a technical standard of writing as much as possible. For your answers, you do not need to hope it helps, since every answer author hopes their material helps. Please leave that out too, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You cannot use FileProvider for removable SD card.
But you can use `root-path` with a warning

> Element root-path is not allowed here

like following

```
<root-path
    name="Name"
    path="." />
```

Comment: Hi Gunaseelan. Of course, whenever we write an answer, we "hope it helps someone", since no-one posts an answer hoping it does not help. It wouldn't matter if you'd added this social nicety once or twice, but you've added 135 times to your posts, which is rather a lot, especially given that volunteer editors will probably remove it. Would you please refrain from adding this to your future answers?

Comment: Ha ha, ROFL, Anyway, I will consider it. Thank you :P

Comment: I don't understand the warning. Why does it work as expected (I use it and it does) if it isn't allowed? The real question about such stupid warnings is: how long will it work until some day the app crashes on a new Android version? I really hate Google for such crap...

Comment: Funny. Years later using "Inspect Code" I stumble over this warning again. I find things like that quite depressing,

Answer (score 0):

> can share files those added from other folders except camera

No. Has nothing to do with camera.

You cannot use FileProvider for removable SD card.